# Removing a character from a certain sed-group

Tags: replace, sed, character

I am trying to remove a character from a certain SED group.

For example

```
sed 's/\(group1\)/\(group2\)/ \1 \2/'
```

I want to remove a certain character from group 2 when it is being displayed.

Thanks!

Comment: Your code is wrong. Post an example along with expected output.

Comment: sed 's/\(Group1\)"\(Group2\)"/\1\2), so lets say I have a string 'Group1"Group2" ', I want to show 'Group1"Goup2" ' => No r

Comment: You'd have to give a broader range of before/after examples. In this case, you can just capture 3 groups:

    sed 's/(Group1)"(G)r(oup2)/\1\2\3/'

which I suspect isn't what you mean.

Comment: I want a sed that will remove a character given any string and placement r for a certain group, if that's even possible. For example, FIRST-HE_LLO to FIRST-HELLO, FIRST-HELL_O to FIRST-HELLO, FIRST-HEL_LO to FIRST-HELLO. FIRST- being group 1. HELLO being group 2.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So I had to make a few assumptions here. Namely...

1. That you know what the group delimiter is (i.e. what will separate these groups that you speak of)
2. That you know how many groups there are - I assumed two but my method could be expanded.
3. That you know what the character is that you want to remove
4. That you only want that character removed from the second group, and not the first (to remove a particular character indiscriminately from a string would be trivial)

I took this on mostly as an academic exercise in the end. Here is what I came up with...

```
#I define the below values in variables for the sake of making this code
#more easily altered to suit your use case. You could of course make this
#a true "one-liner" by hard coding the final command with the values.
#also, the initial echo could really be any command producing that output
#being piped into what is in the curly braces

group_delim="-"
rm_char="_"

echo "F_I_RST-HEL_L_O" | { input=$(< /dev/stdin) &&  first=$(echo ${input} | sed -n "s/\(.*\)\(${group_delim}.*\)/\1/p") && printf ${first}${group_delim} && second=$(echo ${input} | sed -n "s/\(.*${group_delim}\)\(.*\)/\2/p") && echo $second | sed "s/${rm_char}//g" ; }
```

The output is:

```
F_I_RST-HELLO
```

Which is of course the whole string, only with the second group (as defined by the delimiter) with all of the defined "rm_char"s removed.